# Using language constants in external file

Tags: joomla-3.x, language, jtext

How can I use language constant like `JText::_('MY_STRING_FROM_INI_FILE')` in external file?

UPD:
I include joomla system files

```
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/libraries/joomla/factory.php';

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$appUser = JFactory::getUser();
```

but there is effect. Language constants render like MY_STRING_INI, not value of it.

Comment: Please refer to this answer be able to access Joomla classes in your own external file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23937818/1362108

Comment: @Lodder Update question. There is no effect =(

Comment: I will write a proper answer this evening when Im at my computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your language files are not loaded. Load them with `Joomla\CMS\Language\Language::load()`. This example loads `administrator/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_content.ini` file:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$app->initialise();
$app->getLanguage()->load('com_content', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR);
```

Comment: Thanks, adaptize your answer for my task, it's working.